# mongodb aggregate group by name and show avg amount of money for each name

Tags: database, mongodb

show the names, total number of funding rounds, and average amount of money raised from funding rounds for companies that have funding rounds data, excluding those that do not.

I tried the following in the below screenshot link. But the result shows only 0 for average amount.

[image]

```
db.research.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":'$name',"number of funding rounds":  
{ $sum: {"$size":'$funding_rounds'}},"Avg for funding rounds": 
{$avg:"$funding_rounds.raised_amount"} } }])
```

Note: I did $sum instead of $avg but the result is the same.

Below is the sample. raised_amount is in an element of array funding_rounds.
So according to the screenshot, this company's funding_rounds has only one element and its raised_amount is 100000. So the average should be 100000.

[image]

Comment: can you post a sample document and expected output?

Comment: sample is uploaded.

Comment: hey, did you try using `$unwind`?

Comment: $unwind which field?